# hdmi not working - FX706IU

Tags: drivers, hdmi

I have a (**ASUS TUF Gaming A17 FX706IU-H7145T**)
I have installed ubuntu on the machine, but HDMI not working.

There can i download the files? Can you help me?

Thanks for your time

**Edit: 19-04-2021 20.34**

I downloaded it from (https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/146629/) NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run

Install steps:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run
reboot
```

Uninstall steps::

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run --uninstall
reboot
```

Note:
after install reboot, i bootloop login. and i have to uninstall it and so i can login again. I main enter Password and again and again. login loop

Comment: You need Nvida drivers and be running with the Nvida dGPU. Start by opening Additional Drivers and select and apply the recommended version.

Comment: updated questions, i got login loop over and over again.

Comment: A couple of thing you need to learn: 1) always disable Secure Boot in UEFI and 2) NEVER install drivers from the Nvidia's binaries. I explicitly said **"Start by opening Additional Drivers and select and apply the recommended version."**

Comment: So i have to do ? (sudo apt-get install nvidia-430) or do i do it wrong?

Comment: Start by opening Additional Drivers and select and apply the recommended version. i have try that no driver there

Comment: If so you have more problems that just that. Have you installed in UEFI mode as it should be? Is there any setting in UEFI to enable/disable the dGPU?

Comment: There is no settings about dGPU, But there is a (Secure Boot Control) set to disable